# viewPanel: how to set a colspan value for response type view entries

Tags: xpages

Using a **viewPanel**, how can we display a reponse entry the way it is displayed in the Notes client? Or in other words: is there a way to build some kind of colspan for specific columns based on the current entry's document type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some code a while back to make the categorized views behave more like Notes:

http://dontpanic82.blogspot.no/2010/10/xpages-make-categorized-views-behave.html

Here's another solution from Stephan Wissel:

http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86V67E

Comment: way cool, especially the "partial refresh hijacker" topic is helping a lot!